# Is primary key column included at the end of a secondary index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Given these tables

```
Foo
 id (PK)
 name
 updated
```

```
Bar
 foo_id (FK)
 name
 updated
```

And this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo as f
JOIN Bar as b
ON f.id=b.foo_id
WHERE b.name = 'Baz' AND f.name = 'Baz'
ORDER BY f.updated ASC, f.id ASC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 10
```

Are these appropriate indexes to add - in MySql InnoDB the primary key column is automatically added to the end of a secondary index. What is the case with Postgres?

```
CREATE INDEX foo_name_id_idx ON foo(name, id)
CREATE INDEX bar_name_id_idx ON bar(name, id)
```

Comment: No, the PK is not included in an index.

Comment: Unlike MySQL (InnoDB) that uses an clustered index model, PostgreSQL uses a heap model. There are no secondary indexes in PostgreSQL (all are primary indexes), so adding the PK is not mandatory.

Comment: "Are these appropriate indexes to add?" -- It depends on which one you want to act as the driving table. Which one do you want?

Comment: @TheImpaler I think you mean all indexes in Postgres are secondary https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/indexes-index-only-scans.html#:~:text=All%20indexes%20in%20PostgreSQL%20are,the%20index%20and%20the%20heap.

Comment: @RomanDvoskin PostgreSQL uses heaps, that are more performant compared to  clustered indexes (InnoDB). In fact when you create a table it may not have any index at all. When you add an index it becomes just an index (not a primary or secondary one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not make the distinction between primary and secondary indexes, and the primary key index is no different from other indexes. So the primary key is not added to other indexes, and there is no point in doing that unless you have a special reason for it.

Depending on which of the conditions are selective, there are three possible strategies:

1. If the condition on `bar.name` is selective, use `bar` as the driving site:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON bar (name);
   -- foo.id is already indexed
   ```
2. If the condition on `foo.name` is selective:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON foo (name);
   CREATE INDEX ON bar(foo_id);  -- for a nested loop join
   ```
3. If none of the conditions are selective:

   ```
   /* here the "id" is actually at the end of the index,
      but that is just because it appears in ORDER BY */
   CREATE INDEX ON foo (name, updated, id);  -- for the ORDER BY
   CREATE INDEX ON bar (foo_id);  -- for a nested loop join
   ```

Comment: Spot on in terms of performance. The OP wanted to know if the PK is automatically included in any index, and maybe you could add that it's not.

Comment: "...All indexes in PostgreSQL are secondary indexes..." -- Can you elaborate? Would the OID be the primary index, then?

Comment: @TheImpaler: not the OID (of the table),  but the `ctid` of the row

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand. Once a set of tuples is filtered from 1 side, the index has the `ctid`s  that point to the data of the tuples (including the PK column).

"Depending on which of the conditions are selective" How is this determined?

Comment: A condition is selective if it filters out most of the rows, that is, if only few rows remain after it has been applied.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm still lingering with this. To my understanding a `ctid` represents the physical location of the row -- like the ROWID in Oracle or DB2; there's no index on it, but just values. When we create an index on the table its leaves include the ctid. But the ctid by itself doesn't conform an index, does it? Of course, I can be totally wrong here... but I considered PostgreSQL using a similar structure as Oracle and DB2 and this answer kind of challenges my understanding.

Comment: @TheImpaler: it's pretty much the same as in Oracle. Every index entry includes the `ctid`  of the row that is indexed. Just like in Oracle where the index entry contains the `rowid`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then... all indexes are "primary" indexes (as in Oracle and Db2); there are no secondary indexes in PostgreSQL, unlike with SQL Server, SAP ASE, InnodDB (MySQL, MariaDB).

Comment: @TheImpaler There is obviously a lot of confusion about these terms. In databases like PostgreSQL or Oracle there are no primary or secondary indexes, there are just indexes - they are all the same. In InnoDB, however, "each table has a special index called the clustered index that stores row data. Typically, the clustered index is synonymous with the primary key." (quoted from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html)). Other indexes refer to that index and are called secondary indexes. PostgreSQL doesn't have primary indexes in that sense.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The world makes sense again. Thanks.

Comment: For the last option (3), why don't you recommend creating an index on `bar`'s `name` field as well? And what's the general logic for choosing which columns to use based on what is selective?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 `name` is not part of the join condition. Indexing a column whose condition is not selective doesn't make sense.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe But the `name` is not part of the join condition for `foo` either but yet you did include it in the index. So, the question still remains why it is not included for `bar`.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 That was intended to help with the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Right, and the `WHERE` clause checks `name` for both tables. The question still remains..

Comment: @Akaisteph7 I see. The idea is that the execution starts with one of the `WHERE` conditions (the more selective one, typically) then uses a nested loop join to add the matching rows from the other table. You don't need an index on `name` on the second table for that.